# Control flow with iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, control-flow

Say I have something like this:

```cpp
void myFunk(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<T>::iterator first, std::vector<T>::iterator last) {
    while (first != last) {
        if ((*first) > (*last)) {
            T someT;
            v.push_back(someT);
        }
        first++;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<T> foo = {some, T, values};
    myFunky(foo, foo.begin(), foo.end())
    return 0;
}
```

Would this lead to an infinite loop, or would it end after `foo.size()` iterations? In other words, would the `last` iterator be updated as `foo` grew, or would it retain the value given in the function call?

I'm assuming `last` would change, since it's a pointer to a position, but would like some confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this lead to an infinite loop, or would it end after `foo.size()` iterations?

Neither. What you are doing is **undefined behavior**, for a couple of reasons:

- You are modifying the `vector` while iterating through it.

  If the vector reallocates its internal storage when pushing a new item, all existing iterators into the `vector` are *invalidated*, including both iterators you are using to loop with. But even just pushing a new item always invalidates the `end()` iterator, at least.

  See [Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/)
- You are dereferencing the `end()` iterator, which never refers to a valid element.

> I'm assuming `last` would change, since it's a pointer to a position

It can't change, since you passed it into the `myFunc` function by value, so it is a *copy* of the original `end()` iterator.  If `end()` changes value, `last` will not change value, since it is a *copy*.

In any case, iterators are not necessarily implemented as pointers, but pointers are valid iterators. But it doesn't matter in this case. Even if `vector::iterator` were just a simple pointer, `last` would still get invalidated upon every push/reallocation.

Comment: Passing by value was deliberate - the idea was to *try* to make the vector iterate in the current values, while appending new ones at the end. Makes sense i was getting memory access violations at run-time.
Thanks for the invalidation rules plug (I knew what i was looking for was documented but didn't know how to verbalize it). And thanks for the answer man. Really cleared things up. Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest caching the inserts to a local vector, and then append that to the end of the target vector after the iteration is finished.